# Cannot seem to push data to gitlab6 instance. New issues

Tags: push, gitlab

I've created a new project, and I'm trying to add an entire directory to it. I've init'd git in the top directory, added the subdirectory, created a README with content, committed, done the 'git config' steps (user.name, user.email), added the remote. ~/.git/config is identical (save repo name) as that for another project.

When I do a 'git push -u origin master' the command line response tells me everything is up to date. When I go to look at the web instance, though, no files tab is visible.

In addition, I just created a new local repo, and did a git pull. The 2 directories were pulled over, but are empty.

I'm new (obviously) to managing a gitlab repo. I'd like to learn what I'm doing wrong, and how to accomplish what I need (a reliable repo for multiple projects). Right now, I'm fairly confused.